# how to add delegate method into stack view. please

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a junior developer in South Korea.
first of all, my English skill is not so good. I'm sorry.

I hava a question about UIViewController Delegate method

I just want to write featureList from UIViewController to UICollectionViewCell using FeatureDetailViewController

here my code

```
final class AppViewController: UIViewController {
private var featureList: [Feature] = []

private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
private let contentView = UIView() 

private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
   let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    stackView.spacing = 0.0
    
    let featureSectionView = FeatureSectionView(frame: .zero)
    let rankingFeatureSectionView = RankingFeatureSectionView(frame: .zero)
    let exchangeCodeButtonView = ExchangeCodeButtonView(frame: .zero)
 
    let spacingView = UIView()
    spacingView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.height.equalTo(100.0)
    }
    
    [
        featureSectionView,
        rankingFeatureSectionView,
        exchangeCodeButtonView,
        spacingView
    ].forEach {
        stackView.addArrangedSubview($0)
    }
    return stackView
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.addSubview(contentView)
    setupNavigationController()
    setupLayout()
}
```

}

```
private extension AppViewController {
func setupNavigationController() {
    navigationItem.title = "앱"
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true 
}

func setupLayout() {
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top) 
        $0.bottom.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
    }
    
    scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
        $0.width.equalToSuperview() 
    }
    
    contentView.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

}

I just want to present this FeatureDetailViewController when imageview is tapped which is in FeatureSectionCollectionViewCell

here is FeatureSectionCollectionViewCell

```
final class FeatureSectionCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

private lazy var typeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .systemBlue
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12.0, weight: .semibold)
    
    return label
}()

private lazy var appNameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .label
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
    
    return label
}()

private lazy var descriptionLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .secondaryLabel
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .semibold)
    
    return label
}()

private lazy var imageview: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    
    return imageView
}()

func setup(feature: Feature) {
    setupLayout()
    
    typeLabel.text = feature.type
    appNameLabel.text = feature.appName
    descriptionLabel.text = feature.description
    imageview.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    
    if let imageURL = URL(string: feature.imageURL) {
        imageview.kf.setImage(with: imageURL)
    }
}
```

}

```
    private extension FeatureSectionCollectionViewCell {
func setupLayout() {
    [
        typeLabel,
        appNameLabel,
        descriptionLabel,
        imageview
    ].forEach {
        addSubview($0)
    }
}
```

}

and UIView named as FeatureSectionView below

```
final class FeatureSectionView: UIView {
//data from plist
private var featureList: [Feature] = []

private lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    
    collectionView.register(
        FeatureSectionCollectionViewCell.self,
        forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "FeatureSectionCollectionViewCell"
    )
    
    return collectionView
}()

private let separatorView = SeparatorView(frame: .zero)

//FeatureSectionView이 UIView 이므로 ViewDidLoad에서 하지 않고 init 에서 실행
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    setupViews()
    fetchData() //reloadData after read data
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

```
extension FeatureSectionView: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return featureList.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "FeatureSectionCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? FeatureSectionCollectionViewCell
    
    let feature = featureList[indexPath.row]
    cell?.setup(feature: feature)
    
    return cell ?? UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

}

```
extension FeatureSectionView : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width - 32.0, height: frame.width)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 16.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 16.0)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 32.0
}
```

}

```
private extension FeatureSectionView {
func setupViews() {
    [
        collectionView,
        separatorView
    ].forEach {
        addSubview($0)
    }
    collectionView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        $0.top.equalToSuperview().inset(16.0)
        $0.height.equalTo(snp.width)
    }
    
    separatorView.snp.makeConstraints {
        $0.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        $0.top.equalTo(collectionView.snp.bottom).offset(16.0)
    }
}

func fetchData() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Feature", withExtension: "plist") else { return }
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        let result = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Feature].self, from: data)
        featureList = result
    } catch { }              
}
```

}

HOW TO SET DELEGATE METHOD to presentation FeatureDetailViewController when imageview was tapped ?

I know it's hard to read, but I almost half-day-spent. please teach me guys.
thx

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The delegate method would be useful if the user taps the cell in general; however, you want it to transition only when the imageView in the cell is tapped--from what I am understanding.

So, what you need to do is add a tapGestureRecognizer onto your imageView and perform the transition with a selector.

First create a method of the functionality that you want (this will be the selector)

```
@objc func imageWasTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         //perform transition here
      }
}
```

Add a tapGestureRecognizer to the imageView

```
private lazy var imageview: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
    imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    //Make sure it can be touched
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    //Create the Gesture Recognizer and initialize it with the selector
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageWasTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))

    //add the Gesture Recognizer to the view
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    
    return imageView
}()
```